# How to access tag filters in a before(:suite)/before(:all) hook in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to access the tag filters passed in the command line

*Command line*

```
rspec --tag use_ff
```

*RSpec config*

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before :suite, type: :feature do 
    # how do I check if use_ff filter was specified in the command line?
    if filter[:use_ff]
      use_selenium
    else
      use_poltergeist
    end
  end
end
```

In the `before(:suite)` hook I want to access the tag filters specified in the command line in the config.

According to the rspec-core code base the inclusion tag filters are stored in [inclusion_filter](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/950da55279cf8258e64cbb181641b80271fe6cd7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L923) of RSpec.configuration. In theory I should be able to access them as follows:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before :suite, type: :feature do 
    if config.filter[:use_ff] # filter is an alias for inclusion_filter
      use_selenium
    else
      use_poltergeist
    end
  end
end
```

But, for some reason, I get an empty hash even when I pass the tag from the command line.

Comment: This looks interesting, can you also please share any extra information; Some error messages or expected vs what you are getting information.

Comment: I'm sure you've already read [`--tag option`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/command-line/tag-option).

Comment: @vee, essentially I need to access the tag filters specified in the command line. I am hoping that it might be possible to extract the filters from the context or from the before hook has a block parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`config.filter` returns an [`RSpec::Core::InclusionRules`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/filter_manager.rb#L186). Looking in its superclass [`RSpec::Core::FilterRules`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/filter_manager.rb#L115), we see that it has an accessor `.rules` which returns a hash of tags, so you can do, for example,

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    $running_only_examples_tagged_foo = config.filter.rules[:foo]
  end
end

describe "Something" do
  it "knows we're running only examples tagged foo", :foo do
    expect($running_only_examples_tagged_foo).to be_truthy # passes
  end
end
```

(I'm using RSpec 3.4.)

Comment: Looks very interesting. Do you any link to the documentation for this?

Comment: Thanks +1. I will test this out.

Answer (score 0):

@Dave Schweisguth's answer is great but note you can't use `--only-failures` option anymore with it.

(unfortunately, `--only-failures` doesn't work with a tag filter)